# why I am getting "it policies may be restricting access to this folder" while installing "Atom"?

Tags: windows

please solve my problem, I was installing atom then suddenly a pop up showed of "it policies may be restricting access to this folder".
so what can I do to solve it...

Answer (score 0):

you can fix that problem easily by following the steps given below :-

1. Copy the setup from the downloads
2. Go to (C:\Users{user_name}\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_8wekyb3d8bbwe\TempState)
3. Paste the setup in TempState
4. Right click the setup and select run as administrator
5. The app will be downloaded.